# How to click button no id and no class in RobotFramework Please see code below

Tags: robotframework

I'm try login my website use robotframework for example.

```
HTML            
[input type="submit" value="Login"]

--- Variable ---                    
${btn_login}           //*[@input="submit"]

ERROR          
Login rabbitmq - Fail                                                                                                                            | FAIL |             
Element with locator '//*[@input="submit"]' not found.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry I'm try put code ${btn_login} //*[@type="submit"] is work.

Comment: `[input type="submit" value="Login"]` isn't valid html. Or rather, it doesn't represent an `input` tag.

Comment: This code render from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ in my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locator is wrong defined. You should refer to a specific attribute key/value (`type=""`, `value=""` inside of `input`), in your case it will look like:

```
${btn_login}           //input[@type="submit"]
```

To read more about XPath syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp